# How do I access the individual characters of a string in VB6

Tags: string, vb6

Consider the following VB code:

```
    Dim fooBar As String
    fooBar = "Foo Bar"

    Dim q As String
    q = fooBar(0)
```

In VB.Net, this compiles and my **q** string variable is set to the letter "F", however in VB6 I get a compile error, as the compiler expects an array.

I am in a scenario in VB6 where it would be really useful to be able to treat a string this way, as in access the individual characters via an indexer or something similar.

How do I access the individual characters of a string in VB6?

Thankyou

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `Mid`:

```
q = Mid(fooBar, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Thankyou for this, Mid works great however indexing in VB6 seems to start at 1 as opposed to zero, so my final code was `q = Mid(fooBar, 1, 1)` to have **q** equal to "F"

Comment: +1 Here's a link to the [Mid documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445073(v=vs.60)).